# Google Web Font Import doesn't work at end of stack

Tags: html, css, linux, fonts

Google Web Fonts as imported in website does not work properly when they are not the first in the font-stack.

But, when they are first in the font stack, they do work, but I don't need them there.

A week ago I installed Linux as dual boot on my laptop and decided to see how my website looks on Linux - It looked weird, because Linux lacks many fonts, especially my Palatino font - and I decided to find a backup Google font. But it doesn't work as expected now.

The problem is not that fonts are not loading - they are loading:

Sometimes I have webpage in 2 languages, English and Sanskrit (also Hindi), also Google Web Font has Latin and Sanskrit characters. When Web Font is in position 3 or 4, it changes Sanskrit text, but leaves untouched English (Latin) part of text.

However, when Web Font is put first, everything works fine.

```
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sahitya&subset=devanagari';

font-family: 'Sahitya', "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, "Book Antiqua", Georgia, serif;
```

OR

```
font-family: "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, "Book Antiqua", 'Sahitya', Georgia, serif;
```

UPDATE:
The font stack works also with Webfont in 2nd position, i.e. like

```
font-family: "Palatino Linotype", 'Sahitya', Palatino, "Book Antiqua", Georgia, serif;
```

- but not behind *Palatino* font... I suspect there could be something with Quotation Marks?! double or single?! - while I know the general rule is - Quotation marks are necessary only for names consisting of 2 words; but still...?!

UPDATE 2:

The same problem appears not only for imported, but any Linux fonts - if it follows in font stack next to other font of 1 single word

say `font-family: Palatino, Carlito` - doesn't work;

While:

`font-family: "URW Palatino l", Carlito` - work

Comment: `@import` always must be first line of css.

Comment: rule-wise: as per https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts-3/#font-family-prop, the quotation rule is "Font family names other than generic families must either be given quoted as strings, or unquoted as a sequence of one or more identifiers." - an Identifier being a string that [only consists of alphanumerics](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier), so it's `"Palatino Linotype"` and `"Bookman Antiqua"`(with quotes), but `Sahitya` and `Georgia` (no quotes).

Comment: 'Sahitya' - stands for Google webfont, is why per example in single quotes; Palatino, Georgia - without quotes =)

Comment: But on my Windows partition the css font-family works; but on Linux (OpenSuse) - doesn't work...and I cannot find why....

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried imported them in your html header? like this:

http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

Regards,
Pablo

Comment: It's another way of embedding offered by Google; but it would take more troubles for me; I need them in Drupal node; and it's easer to put @import through general stylesheet